# Displaying Hebrew in virtual console

Tags: virtual-console, hebrew

I am using Ubuntu server 16.10, XTerm and Emacs display Hebrew and Arabic script fine.

When used from within the X windowing system, the virtual console itself, that is not the terminal emulator, cannot display Hebrew.

How can it be fixed?

Comment: However, Ubuntu doesn't appear to ship a console font that supports both Hebrew and Arabic script.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. My search of the forum hadn't unearthed that post. As an aside console setup claims to offer support for both Arabic and Hebrew.

Comment: Yes, but not at the same time (at least on Ubuntu 14.04). I can see font maps that include Hebrew and maps that include Arabic but none that includes both.